# Method in ContextMenu for (Hierarchical)DataTemplate calls TreeViewItem's method instead of the one in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, contextmenu

I have a *TreeView* with multiple *HierarchicalDataTemplate & DataTemplate* items and I'm using *Caliburn Micro* for mvvm. The *ItemsSource* for the treeview is pointing to a collection in the viewmodel called 'TreeData' and I tried adding a specific ContextMenu for each HierarchicalDataTemplate & DataTemplate.

In the ContextMenu I use the caliburn functionality "*cal:Message.Attach*" to call a function in the

I made a smaller example of the treeview to illustrate the problem.

In the ViewModel (the collection object):

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // TreeData object
    public ObservableCollection<TestRoot> TreeData = new ObservableCollection<TestRoot>()
    {
        new TestRoot()
        {
            Name = "Root item"
        }
    };

    // the function on the viewmodel that should be called
    public void DoSomething(object item)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MyViewModel - DoSomething called");
    }
}
```

The collection object:

```
public class TestRoot
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // caliburn calls this instead of the one on the viewmodel
    public void DoSomething(object item)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TestRoot - DoSomething called");
    }
}
```

MyView.xaml treeview with only one (Hierarchical)DataTemplate:

```
<TreeView Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeData}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TestRoot}" >

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <!-- caliburn (?) chooses the method on the collection object, not the viewmodel -->
                        <MenuItem Header="test dosomething" cal:Message.Attach="DoSomething($dataContext)"></MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel.ContextMenu>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

In another piece of code, I placed the ContextMenu in the TreeView.ContextMenu. There it worked as it 'should', pointing to the method on the viewmodel.

Looking around for a solution, I see things like "inheritance context". I think it might have something to do with it, but I'm not sure. How can I tell caliburn it must look in the viewmodel for my method, instead of the item in the TreeView I clicked on?

Or is there another possibility? For example: defining the different ContextMenus in the Resources and pointing them to the DataTemplates? But, wont that cause the exact same problem?

Please note that I'd like to keep the code-behind as minimal as possible. Thanks

**update**

For the completeness, here's the real development code. This should be right, no?

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding OrderTreeViewData.OrderTreeViewCategories}"
          cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectedItemChanged] = [Action OnSelectedItemChanged($this)]">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <!-- We have to select the item which is right-clicked on -->
            <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"
                            Handler="TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown"/>
            <!-- set expanded -->
            <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <TreeView.Resources>                   
        <!--  dredge  nodes -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type programs:DredgeRoot}" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Dredgezones}">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Header="Add dredge zone" cal:Message.Attach="TreeViewAddDredgeZone($datacontext)"></MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel.ContextMenu>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <!-- omitted other templates -->

    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is still one tricky part to deal with. Due to the specific `Popup` behavior it doesn't inherit `DataContext`. To access proper context you have to get the `PlacementTarget`:

```
  <StackPanel Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
      <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
               <MenuItem Header="test dosomething" cal:Message.Attach="DoSomething"/>
         </ContextMenu>
      </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
  </StackPanel>
```

Comment: It still is complaining: _No target found for method xxxxx_

Comment: I added your suggestion to the piece of real development code.

Comment: Thanks for your continued effort. While searching around, I also found some code using your suggest "Placement.Tag". But still it doesn't want to recognize the ".Tag" binding. It's driving me crazy and the flu isn't helping too.

Maybe I should try using a Command in the menuItem instead of a function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the nearly same problem as me, maybe see this topic : [Bind contextMenu to a different viewmodel from treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834396/bind-contextmenu-to-a-different-viewmodel-from-treeview)

You can try to use a command :
Try to change you code to :

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="Add dredge zone" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.TreeViewAddDredgeZoneCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" 
                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"></MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
```

Then add to your hierarchicalDataTemplate a Tag and ContextMenu

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type programs:DredgeRoot}" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Dredgezones}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}} ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}">
```

And in your viewmodel you can add your command with something like this :

```
public ICommand TreeViewAddDredgeZoneCommand
    {
        //your code here
    }
```