# Bind contextMenu to a different viewmodel from treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I want to show a contextMenu item when I am using rightclick on a treeview item.

After that, I want to use a command when I click on my MenuItem, but I need to bind the command with a different viewmodel and the command parameter with the good viewmodel who come from my treeview selected item.

So for the moment, I have something like that :

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeViewProtocolsAndEquipments" AllowDrop="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleParams}">

        <TreeView.Resources>
            <!-- CONTEXT MENU -->
            <!-- Protocol -->    
            <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenuProtocol">
                <MenuItem Header="Add new equipment" Command="{Binding AddNewEquipmentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/Add.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <Separator />
            </ContextMenu>

            <!-- MODULE XXX -->
            <!-- ModuleParam > xxx -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xxx:ModuleParamXXXViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleItems}">
                <TextBlock Text="XXX" Foreground="Green" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ContextMenuProtocol}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>

    </TreeView>
```

For the moment my command is bind to xxx:ModuleParamXXXViewModel if I just let { binding }

1. Can I bind my Command to my ActivatedProtocolsAndEquipmentsTreeViewModel (the datacontext of this usercontrol) and keep on the CommandParameter my xxx:ModuleParamXXXViewModel (who is the Item from the treeview where we triggered the right click to show the contextMenu) ?
2. How can I achieve this in an other way with MVVM practice ?

I also tried to use this but it didn't work too :

```
<MenuItem Header="Add new equipment" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddNewEquipmentCommand, Source={x:Reference TreeViewProtocolsAndEquipments}}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

And with this i get *Object Reference not set to an instance of an object*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UserControl` is not a visual ancestor of the `MenuItem` since a `ContextMenu` resides in its own visual tree.

Bind the `Tag` property of the `TextBlock` to the `UserControl` and then bind the `Command` property to the `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu`:

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeViewProtocolsAndEquipments" AllowDrop="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleParams}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <!-- CONTEXT MENU -->
        <!-- Protocol -->
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenuProtocol">
            <MenuItem Header="Add new equipment"
                              Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.AddNewEquipmentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Images/Add.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <Separator />
        </ContextMenu>

        <!-- MODULE XXX -->
        <!-- ModuleParam > xxx -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xxx:ModuleParamXXXViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleItems}">
            <TextBlock Text="XXX" Foreground="Green"
                               Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                               ContextMenu="{StaticResource ContextMenuProtocol}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works but now it never trigger my contextMenu, when i right click on a menu item, it doesn't show the contextMenu but execute the command... My binding is in menu item so, for me, it must be triggered on click on the menu item in the contextmenu and not the moduleitem in the visual tree right ? So why it execute this command like that ?

Comment: It works but you don't see the ContextMenu? This makes no sense I am afraid. Also, changing the bindings as I suggested doesn't cause the ContextMenu to disappear so I don't know what you are doing.

Comment: I am just stupid, I let somewhere in my CommandHandler constructor a _canExecute = true; so it could always execute the command with no more click... Now it works, but I have just the MenuItem disabled so I can't click anymore on it... I will try to find out what's going on (With this visualtree and logicaltree), thank you for help !